# Convert string to date spark sql

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a pretty involved format that does not seem to want to convert correct. It always turn out as null. I am using the SimpleDateFormat formatting to try and do it.

```
Dataset<Row> test = spark.sql("select to_date('Fri Apr 05 08:49:57 CEST 2019', 'EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss CEST yyyy')" );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your timezone format seems wrong. It should be `z` such as

```
spark.sql("""SELECT to_timestamp('Fri Apr 05 08:49:57 CEST 2019', 'EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy') as date""").show(false)
```

where the result is:

```
+-------------------+
|date               |
+-------------------+
|2019-04-05 15:49:57|
+-------------------+
```